# Unable to understand return code of pcregrep when executed from python script

Tags: python, regex, pcre

I am trying to parse a set of regular expression using pcregrep command. This command will be executed from python and the output is formatted and stored in python data structures. I am able to execute all the regular expressions except the below one

```
"^.{159}-{51}\s*\n.{159}Attempting to start (?:ORM(R)?|CPS)  channel\s*\n.*in\s*\n.*init_n_config\s*\n.*H_ICM_C_MCC_CHANNEL_MANAGER\.C\s*\n.*at  line\s*\n.*\d+\s*$"
```

I am printing the error code and along with the message I get by executing pcregrep command from python.

I am getting error code as 256 and empty message
I am using commands utility of python. I am printing cmd_output[0](for return code) and command_output[1] (for error message)
I tried executing this from command line and it works perfectly. It prints all the matching lines matching the above regular expression.

Is there anything I am missing here. Only the above regular expression is giving error. Rest of expressions are working absolutely fine.

Comment: Would help if you could add the piece of code you're using to execute this regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Return code 256 (when using it via Python subprocess calling methods of various kinds) can mean that the subprocess exited normally with exitcode 1 which for a grep means that it didn't find anything.  So this might not be an error but just a failure to find the desired regexp.

Now, that regexp contains several special characters like asterisks and backslashes.  There are lots of ways to hand these over in a wrong way so they get interpreted and thus broken in the process.  I would suggest to have a look at these points.

It would help if you told us more about how you use this regexp pattern, i. e. please post the code in which it is used and what is happening with the results etc.

Comment: Thanks for the info. BUt what is strange is this work fine i.e. it displays the matching lines when the same is executed via command line. Unfortunately I cannot send you the lines that I am trying to match. Because they have path to our source code etc....

Comment: Then probably you have an error in the way the command line is passed to the `pcregrep`.  Most probably it is about quoting.  You might want to call a small shell script instead of `pcregrep` to find out what gets actally passed.  In this shell script you can do this:  `for i; do printf "%q\n" "$i"; done > /tmp/bla`.  Then have a look at `/tmp/bla` to see all arguments passed.

Comment: I am already printing it in my code before executing it. The trace is 'Error in Checking for "^.{159}-{51}\s*\n.{159}Attempting to start (?:ORM(R)?|CPS) channel\s*\n.*in\s*\n.*init_n_config\s*\n.*H_ICM_C_MCC_CHANNEL_MANAGER\.C\s*\n.*at line\s*\n.*\d+\s*$" 
Error in executing pcregrep command and the error is  
Error in executing pcregrep command and the code is 256' I took the text from the trace and I manually executed the command from command line and it works i.e. the regular expression passed from python to pcregrep perfectly works via command line

Comment: I don't like hunting ghosts (bugs which aren't visible in the debug output, just in the behavior), so I suggest strongly to use my way of printing the arguments (i. e. using `printf "%q\n" "$i"` for each argument).  Otherwise the way you chose to look at the values may destroy the problem.

Comment: Sure.. will try that as well